# HTML update input textarea everytime "Submit" it clicked

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<html>
<script> 
    function changeText()
    {        
        document.getElementById("input1").value = <?php echo '"'.$_POST['input'].'"'; ?>; 
        return true;        
    }
</script>
<form name="mainform" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="input" id="input1" />
<input type="submit" onclick = "changeText()" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
<html>
```

i have this code here. can you make it work as intended ? 
everytime i click **Submit**! i want to change the **value** of the textarea to the **last input** the user inserted.

Comment: By the last you mean : I enter "TOTO", click send put "TOTO" on form?

Comment: Look through a form tutorials using PHP. That's pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Do you mean that when you click submit, you want the input box to retain its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP code is parsed by a PHP interpreter before any HTML output is sent to the browser.
If your form action is the same page and the same form will be shown before and after submission, then you can let PHP print the value of the input field directly into it.

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="input1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['input']);" />
```

If you're trying to revert the value of this input field whenever a user clicks the submit button, then your code (even if it's prone to code injection) should work but this is useless since the page will be requested again when submit is clicked.

Comment: This is usefull tips but you didn't provide a solution to his problem

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to fill in

```
 action=""
```

By the name of your file, like

```
action="myFile.php"
```

**Few tips** :

*NEVER* trust the user. The user can manually change the value of the input and send some dangerous values in your $_POST variable. You need to check it using [filter_input()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.filter-input.php) by example.

Like @Charles said this is pretty simple problem, use google next time.[Here for example](https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20make%20form%20html)